# Emma coverage reports and integration tests

Tags: testng, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, emma

Is there any way to get Emma to report integration tests?  Currently our Emma coverage is only showing unit tests.

Adding for clarifcation:
we are using maven to run build and tests.  Are tests are run using testng, not jUnit, and we are running the surefire plugin: maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: What are your integration tests like? Are they also JUnit tests or some kind of GUI tests ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to get Emma to include integration tests in result coverage. I looked at the emma4it plugin but the only documentation I could find was [this blog post from Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/integration-tests-with-maven-part-2-test-coverage-reports/), and couldn't get it to work.

In the end I gave up and moved over to using [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/index.html) instead. It's written by the same people who wrote Emma, and so is intended to be its successor. I haven't tried using it with testng, but I got it working with jUnit by adding the following 'plugin' declaration to a POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```